# react-select detached reset button does not work with disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, searchbar

I have this search bar, that uses react-select, which the design obliged me to create a detached reset button. This reset button should be disabled until the user starts typing and once he clicks on it, it resets the search (obviously) and goes back to the disabled state.

I have this code sample

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const options = [
      { value: "one", label: "One" },
      { value: "two", label: "Two" },
      { value: "three", label: "Three" },
      { value: "four", label: "Four" },
      { value: "five", label: "Five" }
    ];

    this.state = {
      select: {
        value: null,
        options
      },
      isDisabled: true
    };
  }

  setValue = (value) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      select: {
        ...prevState.select,
        value
      }
    }));
  };

  handleChange = (value) => {
    this.setValue(value);
    this.setState({ isDisabled: false });
  };

  handleInputChange = (value) => {
    if (value.length < 1) {
      this.setState({ isDisabled: true });
    }
    if (value.length > 0) {
      this.setState({ isDisabled: false });
    }
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('reset!');  ===> not happening!
    this.setValue(null);
    this.setState({ isDisabled: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { select, isDisabled } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <p>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} disabled={isDisabled}>
            Reset value
          </button>
        </p>
        <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={select.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          options={select.options}
          isSearchable={true}
          isMulti
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

link to the code  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-detached-reset-button-fqr74

The state of the button itself works fine, enables and disables at the right moment, but it totally ignores the click event, and it doesn't reset. If I remove the `disabled` attribute, the click event works, but then I lose the button disabled state.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is onInputChange is called as soon as the select loses focus and disables the button. This will happen if you already selected some values as the value prop will still be empty. Just add a check for any value in the input before disabling the button.

```
 handleInputChange = (value) => {
    if (value.length < 1) {
      this.setState({ isDisabled: true });
    }
    //Check if SELECT has any value
    if (value.length > 0 || !!this.state.select.value) {
     this.setState({ isDisabled: false });
    }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MosheSommers . I'll just correct one little thing in the checking.

`if (value.length < 1 || !!this.state.select.value) {
      this.setState({ isDisabled: true });
    }
    if (value.length > 0 || this.state.select.value) {
     this.setState({ isDisabled: false });
    }`
Now it works just as it should! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @danihazler did you mean `value.length < 1 && !!this.state.select.value` so it's only disabled if they both have no value?